# How to configure Time sequence message filter

Tags: message-filters, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to use time sequence message filter. I wrote the code according to API defined here [Link](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Example_.28C.2B-.2B-.29-2)

This is my code

void callback(const std_msgs::StringConstPtr& info)
{
ROS_INFO("Call is called ");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "test");

ros::NodeHandle n;

message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::String> sub(n, "my_topic", 1);

message_filters::TimeSequencer<std_msgs::String> seq(sub, ros::Duration(0.1), ros::Duration(0.01), 10);

seq.registerCallback(callback);

ros::spin();

return 0;
}

It gives this error
In file included from /opt/ros/jade/include/message_filters/subscriber.h:43:0,
from /lhome/luqman/Work/radar_ros_ws/src/bbox_rviz/src/test_doc.cpp:2:
/opt/ros/jade/include/message_filters/simple_filter.h: In instantiation of ‘message_filters::Connection message_filters::SimpleFilter::registerCallback(void (*)(P)) [with P = const boost::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::String_std::allocator<void > >&; M = std_msgs::String_std::allocator<void >]’:
/lhome/luqman/Work/radar_ros_ws/src/bbox_rviz/src/test_doc.cpp:21:32:   required from here
/opt/ros/jade/include/message_filters/simple_filter.h:96:99: error: no matching function for call to ‘message_filters::Signal1<std_msgs::String_std::allocator<void > >::addCallback(void (*&)(const boost::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::String_std::allocator<void > >&))’
return Connection(boost::bind(&Signal::removeCallback, &signal_, signal_.addCallback(callback)));
^
/opt/ros/jade/include/message_filters/simple_filter.h:96:99: note: candidate is:
In file included from /opt/ros/jade/include/message_filters/simple_filter.h:41:0,
from /opt/ros/jade/include/message_filters/subscriber.h:43,
from /lhome/luqman/Work/radar_ros_ws/src/bbox_rviz/src/test_doc.cpp:2:
/opt/ros/jade/include/message_filters/signal1.h:91:22: note: template message_filters::Signal1::CallbackHelper1Ptr message_filters::Signal1::addCallback(const boost::function<void(P)>&) [with P = P; M = std_msgs::String_std::allocator<void >]
CallbackHelper1Ptr addCallback(const boost::function<void(P)>& callback)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268020/how-to-configure-time-sequence-message-filter/) by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2017-08-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [naveedhd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26074/naveedhd/) on 2017-08-04**:
As stated in [description](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#5), "The TimeSequencer filter guarantees that messages will be called in temporal order according to their header's timestamp". If that is correct, than the given example in docs would be incorrect.

**Comment by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) on 2017-08-09**:
FWIW, there's a StringStamped message type in marti_common_msgs (http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/marti_common_msgs/html/msg/StringStamped.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect that this problem is due to TimeSequencer working with topics having time stamps. which means if you replace `std_msgs::String` with (for example) `geometry_msgs::PoseStamped`, this would compile

---

Originally posted by [naveedhd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26074/naveedhd/) with karma: 161 on 2017-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1